# good way to interact with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, class, object

So what I currently have is my tables in SQL, with table connecting different table, e.g.

```
Table1: id, identifier, other_attributes
Table2: id, identifier, other_attributes
Table3: id, table1_id, table2_id // this connects table 1 and 2.
```

So I have made an object for table1 and table2, allowing things like `$table = new table1($id);` and `$table->getName();` or `$table->setName();`

However, I'm not quite sure if this is the best way? And if it is, would it be best to create another object for table3? or is there better way to do this?

Finally, what I've done is combine getters and setters, meaning `$table->name('somename');` will set the name, and `$table->name();` will get it. Is it wise to combine them? or better to separate them?

Hosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use objects for each really used object (as the name states somehow…).

For example I have a single user-class, which uses data from three different DB-tables. The n:m relation-tables should be implemented as their names indicate. Having a table 'user_has_address', I would implement the SQL-queries on the user-class too (which the uses an Address-class). But data from a table like 'company_has_employees' would reside in a company-class.

And how to name your getters and setters **in PHP** is a matter of coding-convention (e.g. in your company or just your own). You don't need them at all in PHP when using magic-methods (like [__call()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)), but as noted by @JJ, it would make testing easier.

Comment: Ahh using __set() and __get() sounds like an idea to replace the getters and setters, would probably make the rest of the code neater as well. 
Thanks for the info on the relations.

Comment: I would *not* use magic methods to a greater extend because it does not allow you to use auto-completion in your IDE, i.e. you will waste time and is error-prone. Additionally you can not be sure about the exact return type/value which PHPDoc could provide (e.g. "the integer or -1").

Comment: @str "you can not be sure about the exact return type" If that is a requirement, don't use an un-typed language such as PHP, but stick to Java for example…

Comment: @feeela With PHP you can never be sure about the return type, that's correct. But you should know what a used method *should* return. If you have got a getNumber() you will probably want an integer as a result. But the method might instead return null or -1 or something similar. Without PHPDoc you never know what *should* be returned and can not distinguish between different results.

Answer (score 1):

If I were implementing this, I wouldn't use `name('somename')` and `name()` as setters and getters as you have done. It makes it easy to remember the functions however in my opinion it also makes it a lot easier to make and find coding mistakes. You might accidentally type .name() when you actually mean .name(''), etc and finding such errors in code could be difficult.

I would go with `.getName()` and `.setName('somename')` myself. Maybe I'm biased - I have a strong Java background.

Comment: I have actually learnt to use classes because of Java, even though I knew PHP before I knew Java, and I did originally have one getter and setter for each field, but I thought it just looked too clunky, but as feeela suggested, I will be using the magic methods.

Comment: I agree with whats said (and also as @str stated in his answer - setter/getters may be generated by an IDE - which is very useful), but it's not necessary in all cases. jQuery for example does exactly what Hosh Sadiq initially used: one method for getting and setting, see for example [jQuery.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 1):

I would also strongly recommend getName() and setName(). The reason is simple: A good IDE can avoid typing work.

For example you type:

```
$name = 'str';
$table->setN
```

and then code completion can kick in which could lead to $table->setName($name). If you've only got a name($name = null) method, the IDE can not be sure whether or not to suggest an argument. Additionally, it is *veeeery* common to use setX()/getX() which helps to understand your code.